# reloadData not working (called in delegate)

Tags: ios, uitableview

Good Day,

I am using **UITableViewController** to display a **Search Items**.

My code is as follows below:  The problem is, when I call my **GETSEARCH** function in my **viewDidLoad**, it runs and performs the callback **TITLEITEMSRETURNED**. And the **tableView reloads** correctly.

However, if I use the **searchbar and perform the GETSEARCH**. the delegate gets called, the data loaded into the array correctly, but the tableView never gets updated.

However, if I press the grey cross button, the table suddenly updates!!? What gives?

```
-(void)TitleItemsReturned:(NSArray*)titleItems{
    for(TitleItem* titleItem in titleItems){
        // NSLog(@"TITLE: %@ ISBN: %@",titleItem.Title,titleItem.ISBN);
        [searchResults addObject:titleItem];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"RUN");
    networkLayer=[[NLBNetworkLayer alloc]init];
    searchResults=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:500];
//  [networkLayer getBookSearch:TITLE term:@"Inferno"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [networkLayer setDelegate:(id)self];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    TitleItem *titleItem = nil;
    titleItem = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = titleItem.Title;
    NSLog(@"called %@",titleItem.Title);
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"count %d",[searchResults count]);
    return [searchResults count];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller     shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    //[networkLayer getBookSearch:TITLE term:searchBar.text];
    [networkLayer getBookSearch:TITLE term:@"Inferno"];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"all removed");
    [searchResults removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure after searching completed the table reload is happen?

Comment: can you show me your getBookSearch method in networklayer?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are sending the `reloadData` message from the main thread, otherwise you can have problems. It appears that the `TitleItemsReturned` method may not be called from the main thread (e.g. from a background thread in a `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method implemented by the `networkLayer` object, or a similar delegate method).

If `TitleItemsReturned` is indeed not being run on the main thread, you can do this inside of `TitleItemsReturned`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

The `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method is working because that method is running on the main thread (from a UI event).